# 'object length is not a multiple of shorter object length' after ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I've gone through the other Q&As for this error but still unable to resolve my issue.

I have two data frames which look something like:

```
partID <- c('partA', 'partB', 'partC')
model <- c('model1', 'model1', 'model2')
dfOne <- data.frame(partID, model)
partID <- c('partC', 'partA', 'partA', 'partB', 'partC', 'partX')
dfTwo <- data.frame(partID)
dfTwo$model <- 'diffModel'
```

I am trying to replace the models in dfTwo with those in dfOne matched by partID.  I have tried doing this with ifelse:

```
dfTwo$model <- ifelse(dfTwo$partID == dfOne$partID, 
                  dfOne$model, dfTwo$model)
```

However, I get the error:

> "Warning messages: 1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :   longer object
>   length is not a multiple of shorter object length 2: In
>   `==.default`(dfTwo$partID, dfOne$partID) :   longer object length is
>   not a multiple of shorter object length"

I thought it might be because model in dfTwo was a character and model in dfOne was a factor but I still get the same after I run:

```
dfTwo$model <- as.factor(dfTwo$model)
```

I assume its because the number of observations differ but I'm not quite sure how else to go about this where I don't overwrite those models which don't have a partID match.

I'm still fairly new to using R.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may need a `merge` as the number of rows in both datasets are different for doing `==`

Comment: @akrun agreed. Just wrote something along the lines of
`unique(
  merge(dfOne, dfTwo,by = "partID", all=TRUE)
  )`

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);left_join(dfTwo, dfOne, by = "partID") %>% mutate(model = ifelse(!is.na(model.y), as.character(model.y), as.character(model.x)))`

Comment: Great, thanks both for your help

Comment: And of course ... data.table Phil ;)

Comment: :) I'm just about getting my head around dplyr at the mo